# ¿Como añadir permisos a PDF con iText 5.0?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Mi problematica es la siguiente: Estoy generando un `PDF` desde `Java` con el apoyo de la librería `iText 5.0`, al `PDF` le quiero añadir que no se permita copiar el contenido del archivo, buscando por internet me encontre con la siguiente lineas de código:

```
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, arrayOutputStream);
//No deseo añadir contraseña por eso en los dos primeros parámetros paso null  
writer.setEncryption(null, null, PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING, PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
writer.createXmpMetadata();
```

Pero al momento de ejecutar la descarga no me genera el PDF ni me lanza un error, ¿Alguien tendrá alguna opción para poder realizar lo que ando buscando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despues de un poco de investigación, encontre que `iText 5.0.x` trabaja de la mano con la librería `bcprov-jdk15on`, la cual permite trabajar con certificados y encriptación.

Para resolver mi problema solo agregue la libreria al proyecto, ya no tuve problemas para generar el `PDF` y añadir los permisos al archivo.

Link de descarga librería [bcprov-jdk15on](https://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html).